Getting a lot of crashes for gms in bacground
Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
eaax
alym.d (:com.google.android.gms@243734022@24.37.34 (150400-679256246):5)
aiao.\<clinit\> (:com.google.android.gms@243734022@24.37.34 (150400-679256246):9)
com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.DynamiteLoaderImpl.\<init\> (:com.google.android.gms@243734022@24.37.34 (150400-679256246):49)
java.lang.Class.newInstance (Class.java)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zzg (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.2.0:5)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.2.0:28)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zze.zzb (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.2.0)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.zzi.selectModule (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.2.0:2)
com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.load (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.2.0:7)
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzee.zzf (zzee.java:2)
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzcx.zza (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.1.1:3)
com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzdt.run (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@21.1.1:2)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)

Getting above crashes with multiple different files in gms. These crashes occurs 100% in background and 100% proximity on according to crashlytics. Any one know any reason why this might be happening?
Besides solution, it will be great help if anyone knows when and why this crash occurs. Also the instances of this crash are like 200-500 crashes per single user.
Tried including whole gms library in proguard but that increases size of app by a lot. Like 20 to 26 MB
